# I keep getting unexpected token )

Tags: javascript

I'm doing coding academy, and I am usually doing it right when I get that annoying little message,

```
("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === )
{
console.log("The answer makes sense!");
} 
else 
{
console.log("Error! Error! Error!");
}
```

Comment: Syntax errror in your comparison (value after `===`is missing).

Comment: Also Where is `if` keyword??

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in this line

```
("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === )
```

First, you need some sort of conditional at the beginning of the line, like an `if`

```
if("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === )
```

Second, you need to fill the right side of the equation after the `===` with your target for comparing, like a number

```
if("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 1)
```

Comment: I don't know why there was a downvote, I didn't do that. Sorry, though.

Comment: @Rinita, you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer if you found it helpful to guide future readers of this post